# PHP/MYSQL display mysql record age using datediff

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP/MYSQL, I'm trying to display the age of all records from my database using `DATEIFF` as shown in the line 17 of my code, but it just won't work. I need somebody to help me out with this.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM growers");

echo "<table class='table table-striped table-advance table-hover'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th><i class='icon_profile'></i>&nbsp;Batch</th>
            <th><i class='icon_ol'></i>&nbsp;Date Received</th>
            <th><i class='icon_clock_alt'></i>&nbsp;Age when Received</th>
            <th><i class='icon_clock_alt'></i>&nbsp;Current Age</th>
            <th><i class='icon_star'></i>&nbsp;NO of Birds</th>
            <th><i class='icon_info'></i>&nbsp;View More</th>
        </tr>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo"<tr>";
            echo"<td>" . $row['BATCH'] . "</td>";
            echo"<td>" . $row['BIRTH DAY'] . "</td>";
            echo"<td>" . $row['AGE'] . "&nbsp;Week(s)" . "</td>";
            echo"<td>" . "SELECT DATEDIFF("NOW()", "$row['BIRTH DAY']") AS CURRENT AGE". "</td>";
            echo"<td>" . $row['NO OF BIRDS'] . "</td>";
            echo"<td>" . $row['AGE'] . "</td>";
            echo"</tr>";
        }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: The line `echo"<td>" . "SELECT DATEDIFF("NOW()", "$row['BIRTH DAY']") AS CURRENT AGE". "</td>"` is really messy. You are trying to execute a query and output the result but it would actually just show the query. Calculate the `DATEDIFF()` inside the query in the first line, as suggested by @scaisEdge's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select in main select

```
  $result = mysqli_query($con,
         "SELECT 
        growers.BATCH, 
        growers.`BIRTH DAY`, 
        growers.AGE,            
        DATEDIFF(NOW(),growers.`BIRTH DAY`) AS CURRENT_AGE,
        growers.`NO OF BIRDS`            
        FROM growers; "
   );


                        echo "<table class='table table-striped table-advance table-hover'>
                         <tbody>
                      <tr>
                         <th><i class='icon_profile'></i>&nbsp;Batch</th>
                         <th><i class='icon_ol'></i>&nbsp;Date Received</th>
                         <th><i class='icon_clock_alt'></i>&nbsp;Age when Received</th>
                         <th><i class='icon_clock_alt'></i>&nbsp;Current Age</th>
                         <th><i class='icon_star'></i>&nbsp;NO of Birds</th>
                         <th><i class='icon_info'></i>&nbsp;View More</th>
                      </tr>";

                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                        {
                         echo"<tr>";
                         echo"<td>" . $row['BATCH'] . "</td>";
                         echo"<td>" . $row['BIRTH DAY'] . "</td>";
                         echo"<td>" . $row['AGE'] . "&nbsp;Week(s)" . "</td>";
                         echo"<td>" . $row['CURRENT_AGE'] . "</td>";
                         echo"<td>" . $row['NO OF BIRDS'] . "</td>";
                         echo"<td>" . $row['AGE'] . "</td>";
                         echo"</tr>";
                        }
                        echo "</table>";

                        mysqli_close($con);
                        ?>
```

Comment: Thanks scaisEdge. But my table displayed nothing after i applied the suggestion.

Comment: Nothings for CURRENT_AGE or nothing for all the fields?

Comment: The whole table disappeared, except for the headers

Comment: Seems no result from  Select  ... Are you sure that  `BIRTH DAY`  is    date  type column?   .. i have update the answer ..using explicit column name and backtics  .

Comment: Thanks scaisEdge, i've sorted it out. There was an issue with my database columns